# send data from child to parent in react using props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a child component

```
const Angle = ({ marbles,handleViewMore }) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const classes = useStyles();
    const gridCount = marbles.count <= 4 ? 12 / (marbles.count) : 2



    return (
        <Grid container rowSpacing={0} columnSpacing={{ xs: 2, sm: 2, md: 3 }}>

            <Grid item xs={12} style={{ textAlign: 'centre' }}>

                <Typography className={classes.angle} variant="h6">
                    <span className={classes.angleNoLabel}>angle no:</span>
                    <span className={classes.angleText}>
                        {marbles._id}
                    </span> </Typography>

            </Grid>

            {marbles.marbles.map((marble) => (
                <Grid className={classes.marbleGrid} item xs={gridCount}>
                    <img className={classes.img} src={marble.image} /><br />
                    <span className={classes.marbleName}>{marble.qualityName}</span><br/>
                    <Button onClick={handleViewMore} variant="text">VIEW MORE</Button>
                </Grid>
            ))}


        </Grid>

 );
};
```

And I have parent,

```
const handleViewMore = (marble) => {
  console.log("click");
}

const Map =() => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const classes = useStyles();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getMarblesAnglewise());
      }, []);

    const marblesAnglewise = useSelector((state) => state.marbles);


  return (
    !marblesAnglewise.length ? <CircularProgress /> : (
        <Grid container className={classes.container} container alignItems="stretch" spacing={3}>
          {marblesAnglewise.map((marbles) => (
            <Grid className={classes.angles} container key={marbles._id} item xs={12} sm={4} md={4}>
                <Angle marbles={marbles} handleViewMore={handleViewMore}/>
            </Grid>
          ))}
          {/* <CustomSnackbar openState={snackbarOpenProp} childText={snackbarChildProp} handleSnackBarCloseProp={handleSnackBarCloseAction}/> */}
          <CartDialog dilaogOpenProp={false} marbleDetail/>
        </Grid>
      )
  );
}

export default Map;
```

Angle is a child of Map, I have defined a function in Parent Map named **handleViewMore** as you can see I am sending that it as a props Angle, In Angle I am invoking that func on click, it's functioning fine,but when I am trying to pass parameter in that same fn, it's automatically running on each loop, Like this

```
<Button onClick={handleViewMore(marble)} variant="text">VIEW MORE</Button>
```

After adding this, it does not change for onClick, it runs on Load, what is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is calling the function *immediately* and using the *result* of the function as the `onClick` handler:

```
onClick={handleViewMore(marble)}
```

Instead, wrap this operation in a function and pass that function *itself* to the `onClick` handler instead of invoking it right away:

```
onClick={() => handleViewMore(marble)}
```